# Why doesn't Mathematica simplify $ie^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}(1+a+b)}$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider this

```
I * Exp[-I Pi / 2 * (1+a)] // Simplify
```

Mathematica understands that it is possible to cancel $i$ with $e^{-i\pi/2}$ and gives the result $e^{ia\pi/2}$ as expected. But if we try instead

```
I * Exp[-I Pi / 2 * (1+a+b)] // Simplify
```

Mathematica for some reason doesn't understand that it is still possible to simplify $i$ with $e^{-i\pi/2}$ and it just gives back the same thing, i.e., $ie^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}(1+a+b)}$, which is very weird to me.

What is behind this weird behavior of Simplify and FullSimplify? Why in the first case Mathematica recognizes the simplification and in the second it doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

```
I * Exp[-I Pi / 2 * (1 + a + b)] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify
```

> E^(-(1/2) I (a+b) [Pi])

Answer (score 4):

Instead of just posting workarounds, I will explain why they work. `Simplify` is a discrete, global minimization solver that minimizes a `ComplexityFunction`. The default `ComplexityFunction` is `` Simplify`SimplifyCount ``:

```
(* input *)
I*Exp[-I  Pi/2*(1 + a + b)] // Simplify`SimplifyCount

(* 18 *)

(* a potential intermediate step *)
I*Exp[-I  Pi/2*(1 + a + b)] // ExpandAll // Simplify`SimplifyCount

(* 33 *)

(* desired output *)
Exp[-I  Pi/2*(a + b)] // Simplify`SimplifyCount

(* 13 *)
```

`Simplify` searches for the minimum trying steps from a defined set of `TransformationFunctions`. If a short sequence of steps raises the complexity too much, the sequence is rejected and `Simplify` goes back to least complex expression found. At some point it gives up and returns the best answer found. The exact algorithm is unknown to me, so I cannot comment on the heuristics and thresholds it uses for determining when to continue and when to stop. It is known that it may work on subexpressions as well as the whole expression.

*Workaround by adjustment of `ComplexityFunction`:*

```
Simplify[I*Exp[-I  Pi/2*(1 + a + b)], 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 3 Count[#, I, Infinity] &)]

(* E^(-(1/2) I (a + b) \[Pi]) *)
```

The coefficient `3` of `Count` was the minimally successful choice, which I determined by trial and error. I first picked something greater than `20`, due to the results of `SimplifyCount` above.

*@Domen's solution, implemented as an additional `TransformationFunction`:*

```
Simplify[I*Exp[-I  Pi/2*(1 + a + b)], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Simplify@*ExpandAll}]

(* E^(-(1/2) I (a + b) \[Pi]) *)
```

*Inspecting the process:*

```
Simplify[I*Exp[-I  Pi/2*(1 + a + b)], 
 ComplexityFunction -> Simplify`SimplifyCount@*Echo]
```

`Echo` will print all the steps tested by the `ComplexityFunction`. Use wisely: the number of steps a computer can make in a few milliseconds might overwhelm the Frond End. In this case it is only a few dozen. Also, in my implementation of @Domen's idea, `Simplify` calls `Simplify`: Beware infinite loops. In this case, the inner `Simplify` does not inherit the `TransformationFunctions` of the outer `Simplify`. So the inner one does not call `Simplify` again.

*Added in update*

Here is a safer use of `ComplexExpand` (@AsukaMinato's idea):

```
Simplify[I*Exp[-I  Pi/2*(1 + a + b)], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, 
   FullSimplify@ComplexExpand[#, {a, b}] &}]

(* E^(-(1/2) I (a + b) \[Pi]) *)
```

`ComplexExpand` (resp. `PowerExpand`) assumes variables are real (resp. positive). For `ComplexExpand`, the second argument specifies which variables are to be treated as complex. Using assumptions, when they are true, usually helps; when they are not true, the danger is that invalid transformations might be used. In cases where assumptions are unspecified, the `ExpandAll` solution makes a valid transformation. The drawback to `ExpandAll` is the risk of a combinatorial explosion of terms in a more complicated input.

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a limit to what Simplify can do.

Here is another alternative

```
expr = I*Exp[-I  Pi/2*(1 + a + b)];
Simplify@TrigToExp@Simplify@ExpToTrig@expr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Another method with using [`ExpandAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html) prior to `Simplify`.

```
I*Exp[-I Pi/2*(1 + a + b)] // ExpandAll // Simplify
(* E^(-(1/2) I (a + b) π) *)
```